# DART: Transformer library "package:di/transformer.dart" not found

Tags: dart, angular-dart, dart-editor, dart-pub

Updated to the latest version of dart-sdk (1.3.3) as of today (April 23, 2014).  Downloaded latest DART editor package as of today.

Upgraded AngularDART from version 0.9.x to 0.10.0 with the following changes:

```
NgController -> Controller
NgComponent -> Component

NgBootstrap -> applicationFactory
```

The application works with Dartium but it does not work with PUB BUILD with the following error:

```
--- 7:21:35 PM Running pub build ... ---
Pub build failed, [1] Loading source assets... (0.7s)
Loading di transformers... (1.9s)
Transformer library "package:di/transformer.dart" not found.
```

Look into packages:di/transformer.dart and this file exists in my workspace.  Don't know what's wrong with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is working without any code changes. After I re-download the entire Dart Editor and use the new one.  It works now.

Answer (score 2):

It is probably related to this dart proxy problem: http://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=15161

pub build have a bug that requires HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY to be unset.

```
Unx:
$ env --unset=http_proxy --unset=https_proxy pub build

Windoze:
c:\>set HTTP_PROXY=
c:\>set HTTPS_PROXY=
c:\>pub build
```

I also recommend clearing your pub cache (AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache), because it may become corrupt and persist the problem.

Comment: there is a new `pub cache repair` command (recently added so it may not be available in your version)